# How can I use regex to add tracking parameters to certain domain links?

Tags: php, regex, google-analytics

I try to add Google Analytics tracking parameters to urls from a newsletter stored in database.
If I use this:

```
preg_replace('/href="([^"]+)/', "$1?utm_source=NEWSLETTER", $text);
```

I will have all the urls changed, but I need to change only the urls with certain domain, for example **domain.com**.
Can I use regex for this task?

Thanks to Avinash Raj I almost had the solution. I only added **href=""** to the replacement variable and it was done!

```
preg_replace('~href="([^"]*\bdomain\.com[^"]*)~', 'href="$1?utm_source=NEWSLETTER"', $text);
```

Comment: `preg_replace('~href="([^"]*\bdomain\.com[^"]*)~', "$1?utm_source=NEWSLETTER", $text);`

Comment: sidenote: at a minimum, you are required to specify utm_source,utm_name, and utm_medium if you want GA to track your campaign. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

Comment: Thank you, sidenote, for your answer!
I know I need more parameters for GA tracking but I just put one for example :) In the code I will use all the parameters I need.